# Transform BeatifulSoup results into lists

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm new in python, and I'm doing a challenge for an open position. I have to do an ETL, and I'm stuck at some point. How I can transform my bs4 results into an list, so I can order?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

url = "http://challenge.dienekes.com.br/api/numbers?page="

for page in range(1, 10000):
    req = requests.get(url + str(page))
    soup = bs(req.text, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour] and read [ask] to improve, [edit] and format your questions. Thanks (What is the expected output?)

Comment: The expected output are some lists of numbers. In each page they gave me this:
{"numbers":[0.4181707133672159,0.4446014940576127,0.3364303523294636,0.4135426519101487,0.2245623856417824,0.6501239000539522,0.5998745794215936,0.6354200131296106,0.5000394301387743,0.11919252546814178,0.015621683926585785,0.038535707538389585,0.5887652298728361,0.3039725579091457,0.1774558105104917,0.42900248202339797,0.2601173525819016,0.4266699497985482,0.3760371623556028,0.6254643842}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your request returns no HTML document, but just a list of numbers, you do not need to parse the page via bs4.

You could, e.g., just parse the returned values via

```python
numbers = req.json()
```